# Can I get Command-H to hide an Emacs window?

Tags: emacs, keyboard

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2012-01-29 on bob.porkrind.org on a MacBook Air.

Can I set <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to hide Emacs? I currently use M-x customize-group ns and set Command Modifier to no value. I already have a standard key binding to iconify-frame, but that is different from hiding; I'd rather use the native OS X hide capability so I can unhide by clicking on the Emacs icon in the dock.

Answer (score 6):

If emacs is built with Cocoa (e.g via [`brew install emacs --cocoa`](https://brew.sh/)), by default `s-h` (Cmd+h) should be bound to `ns-do-hide-emacs`

If somehow it is not, you can do this manually with:

```
(global-set-key [(super h)] 'ns-do-hide-emacs)
```

Comment: If you have bound *Command* to *Meta* then the binding is:
`(global-set-key [(meta h)] 'ns-do-hide-emacs)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve the same problem. The best I've been able to come up with is the following, which will iconify (like CMD+M) the frame:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-h") 'iconify-frame)
```

Not ideal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

2023 calling - emacs 29.1
spacemacs
paste this into my .spacemacs

`(global-set-key [(hyper h)] 'ns-do-hide-emacs)`